# using simple_html_dom & cURL but did not get all contents of the page. How can I get?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The problem is, I get some parts of the contents but did not get the user's reviews. by Firebug I saw contents but when I checked the source codes NO contents inside HTML tags / no same HTML tags. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    //Headers 
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

function getPage($page, $redirect = 0, $cookie_file = '')
{         
   $ch = curl_init();


   $headers = array("Content-type: application/json");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

   if($redirect)
   {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);    
   }

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page);

   if($cookie_file != '') {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
   }

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.6) Gecko/20060728 Firefox/1.5.0.6');

   $return = curl_exec($ch);  //Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)

   curl_close($ch);

   return $return;

}//EO Fn

//Source 
$url = 'http://www.vitals.com/doctor/profile/1982660171/reviews/1982660171';


//Parsing ... 
$contents = getPage($url, 1, 'cookies.txt'); 

$html = str_get_html($contents); 
//Output
echo $html->outertext;
?>
```

Can anyone please help me - what I should do to get the whole page so that I can grab reviews?`enter code here`

Comment: My bet is those comments are added using Ajax. There's no simple fix for this - plus you probably [shouldn't be scraping that site in the first place.](http://www.vitals.com/termsofuse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just stored as JSON in a `<script>` block towards the top of the page. Parse it out with RegEx or Simple HTML DOM and run it through [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
var json = {"provider":{"id":"1982660171","display_name":"Stephen R Guy, MD","last_name":"Guy","first_name":"Stephen","middle_name":"Russell","master_name":"Stephen_Guy","degree_types":"MD","familiar_name":"Stephen","years_experience":"27","birth_year":"1956","birth_month":"5","birth_day":"23","gender":"M","is_limited":"false","url_deep":"http:\/\/www.vitals.com\/doctor\/profile\/1982660171\/Stephen_Guy","url_public":"http:\/\/www.vitals.com\/doctors\/Dr_Stephen_Guy.html","status_code":"A","client_ids":"1","quality_indicator_set":[{"type":"quality-indicator\/consumer-feedback","count":"2","suboverall_set":[{"name_short":"Promptness","overall":"3"},{"name_short":"Courteous Staff","overall":"4"},{"name_short":"Bedside Manner","overall":"4"},{"name_short":"Spends Time with Me","overall":"4"},{"name_short":"Follow Up","overall":"4"}],"name":"Consumer Reviews","overall":"4.0","measure_set":[{"feedback_response_id":"1756185","input_source_ids":"{0}","date":"1301544000","value":"4","scale":{"best":"1","worst":"4"},"review":{"type":"review\/consumer","comment":"I will never birth with another dr.  Granted that's not saying much as I don't like dr's but I actually find him as valuable as the midwives who I adore.  I liked Horlacher but when Kitty left I followed the midwives and then followed again....Dr. Guy is GREAT.  I honestly don't know who I'd rather support me at my birth; Margie and Lisa or Dr. Guy.  ....I wonder if I can just get all of them.Guy's great.  Know what you want.  Tell him.  Be strong and he'll support you.I give him 10 stars.  Oh...my baby's 3 years old now.  He's GREAT! ","date":"1301544000"},"sub_measure":[{"name":"Waiting time during a visit","name_short":"Promptness","value":"3","scale":{"best":"4","worst":"1"}},{"name":"Courtesy and professionalism of office staff ","name_short":"Courteous Staff","value":"4","scale":{"best":"4","worst":"1"}},{"name":"Bedside manner (caring)","name_short":"Bedside Manner","value":"4","scale":{"best":"4","worst":"1"}},{"name":"Spending enough time with me","name_short":"Spends Time with Me","value":"4","scale":{"best":"4","worst":"1"}},{"name":"Following up as needed after my visit","name_short":"Follow Up","value":"4","scale":{"best":"4","worst":"1"}}]},{"feedback_response_id":"420734","input_source_ids":"{76}","link":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/info-15826842-guy-stephen-r-md-university-women-s-health-center-dayton","date":"1142398800","value":"4","scale":{"best":"1","worst":"4"},"review":{"type":"review\/consumer","comment":"Excellent Doctor: I really like going to this office. They are truely down to earth people and talk my \"non-medical\" language. I have been using thier office since 1997 and they have seen me through 2 premature pregnancies!","date":"1142398800"}}],"wait_time":"50"}]}};
```

But again, make sure you have permissions to do this...

Comment: I am just learning scraping - and also very new in this field. Simple pages I can. Could you please write me some codes to how to parse this "var json ={..." by simple HTML DOM or RegEx.